# Apollo client writeQuery updates stores, but UI componens only updates after the second function call

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

```
"apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.2",
"apollo-client": "^2.6.3",
```

I setup a simple subscription with the client.subscribe method and try to update the store with the client.writeQuery method

```
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.purchaseSubscription = client.subscribe({
      query: PURCHASE_ASSIGNED_SUBSCRIPTION,
      variables: { status: ['INPREPARATION', 'PROCESSED', 'READYFORCOLLECTION', 'ONTHEWAY', 'ATLOCATION'] },
    }).subscribe({
      next: (subscriptionData) => {
        const { cache } = client;
        const prev = cache.readQuery({
          query: MY_PURCHASES,
          variables: { status: ['INPREPARATION', 'PROCESSED', 'READYFORCOLLECTION', 'ONTHEWAY', 'ATLOCATION'] },
         });
        const newPurchase = subscriptionData.data.purchaseAssignedToMe;
        const data = { myPurchases: [...prev.myPurchases, newPurchase] };

        cache.writeQuery({
          query: MY_PURCHASES,
          variables: { status: ['INPREPARATION', 'PROCESSED', 'READYFORCOLLECTION', 'ONTHEWAY', 'ATLOCATION'] },
          data,
        });
      },
      error: (err) => { console.error('err', err) },
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <AppContainer />
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

The store gets updated after the call, however the UI component is only re-rendered only on the second publish event.

The UI components is setup the following way:

```
  <Query
    query={MY_PURCHASES}
    variables={{ status: ['INPREPARATION', 'PROCESSED', 'READYFORCOLLECTION', 'ONTHEWAY', 'ATLOCATION'] }}
    >
   ...
  <Query />
```

By reading the cache after the writeQuery is called I was able to validate that the store reflect the proper state, however the UI component only gets updated at every  second call.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ApolloClient.subscribe's next function is very similar to how updateQueries works in Apollo Client’s mutate function, but with the exception that `cache.writeQuery` does not broadcast the changes if it is not called from the the Mutation's update function.

**SOLUTION: use `client.writeQuery(...)` instead of `cache.writeQuery(...)`**

> Note: The update function receives cache rather than client as its
> first parameter. This cache is typically an instance of InMemoryCache,
> as supplied to the ApolloClient constructor when the client was
> created. In case of the update function, when you call
> cache.writeQuery, the update internally calls broadcastQueries, so
> queries listening to the changes will update. **However, this behavior
> of broadcasting changes after cache.writeQuery happens only with the
> update function. Anywhere else, cache.writeQuery would just write to
> the cache, and the changes would not be immediately broadcast to the
> view layer. To avoid this confusion, prefer client.writeQuery when
> writing to cache.**
>
> Source: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations/#updating-the-cache

Comment: Dude, I spent hours n hours figuring this out. Thanks a lot.